# parsing XML to ListView Android

Tags: java, android, xml

How to display only those lines in which the `parent_id=0` in

https://api.api2cart.com/v1.0/category.list.xml?api_key=6aed775211e8c3d556db063d12125d2d&store_key=ed58a22dfecb405a50ea3ea56979360d&start=0&count=38&params=id,name,parent_id,images?

**CatalogActivity.java**

```
public class CatalogActivity extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

static final String URL = "https://api.api2cart.com/v1.0/category.list.xml?api_key=6aed775211e8c3d556db063d12125d2d&store_key=ed58a22dfecb405a50ea3ea56979360d&start=0&count=38&params=id,name,parent_id,images";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "category";
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_PARENT_ID = "parent_id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "name";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "http_path";
String Parend_id;
int id_parent;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> catalogList;

//@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    catalogList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new LoadCatalog().execute();
}

    class LoadCatalog extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>   {

         @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CatalogActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка каталога ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

         protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
             XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value
                    Parend_id=map.put(KEY_PARENT_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PARENT_ID));
                    map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                    map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    catalogList.add(map);
                }
                return null;

         }


         protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */
                        list=getListView();
                        adapter=new LazyAdapter(CatalogActivity.this, catalogList);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }
   // list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id,list);


    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList


    // Click event for single list row
    /*list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });*/
}
 }
```

**CatalogAdapter.java**

```
public class CatalogAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public Activity activity;
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
public static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
String Parend_id;
int id_parent;

public CatalogAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catalog_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> catalog_list = new HashMap<String, String>();
    catalog_list = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(catalog_list.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(catalog_list.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}

  }
```

Comment: what is the problem in your code?

Comment: In code no problem. I do not know how to display only those lines in which the parent_id=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check parent id before adding item to the ArrayList(catalogList) and add item if only id is 0 or you can copy this Arraylist to another list by putting required validation of parent id  must be 0.

Comment: Where to write? In CatalogActivity.java or CatalogAdapter.java? I've tried in <b>CatalogActivity.java</b>: <br>String Parend_id; int id_parent; Parend_id=map.put(KEY_PARENT_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PARENT_ID)); id_parent=Integer.parseInt(Parend_id); if(id_parent==0){
                    map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                    map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));}  App does not work.

Comment: try this in you doinbackground of activity class
if(parser.getValue(e, KEY_PARENT_ID)==0)
{
   HashMap<String, String> map_new = new HashMap<String, String>();
   map_new.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
   map_new.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
   map_new.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
   new_catalogList.add(map_new);
}
Pass this new catalog list to your adapter in postExecute()

Comment: instead if(parser.getValue(e, KEY_PARENT_ID)==0) I write if(parser.getValue(e, KEY_PARENT_ID).equals("0")) and is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your AsyncTask write right after ParentId = ...

```
if(ParentId.equals("0")){
  continue;
}
```

HINT: getItem(int pos) should return the model at position, sth.like

```
public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position){
    return data.get(position);
}
```

in getView(....):

HashMap catalog_list = getItem(position);